# llamar función con parámetros en el Page Load .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

Estoy haciendo un formulario de filtrar por 3 criterios, estoy teniendo problemas en la paginacion ya que no me carga los datos de la segunda pagina del GV, al parecer tengo que llamar mi funcion que llena el GV en el page Load de la pagina, pero resulta que esta funcion recibe parametros que son los que el usuario introduce en el filtro de busqueda, como puedo entonces llamar la funcion enviando los parametros a esa funcion en el page Load cada que se cambie de pagina en el GV

funcion

```
    public DataTable BuscarAnuncio(string tituloAnuncio, DateTime fechaInicial, DateTime fechaFinal)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Util.ObtenerCadenaConexion("ConnectionString"));
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "select*from where titulo=@titulo or fechaI=@fecha1" or fechaF=@fecha2;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@titulo", tituloAnuncio == "" ? (object)DBNull.Value : tituloAnuncio);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fechaI", fechaInicial == "" ? (object)DBNull.Value : fechaInicial);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FechaF", fechaFinal == "" ? (object)DBNull.Value : fechaFinal);
    cmd.Connection = con;
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    return dt;
}
```

boton buscar

```
        protected void BtnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            GridView1.DataSource = BuscarAnuncio(txtTitulo.Text,txtFechaI.Text,txtFechaF.Text);
            GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías capturar los valores **txtTitulo.Text, txtFechaI.Text y txtFechaF.Text** en el método **BuscarAnuncio**, así evitarías tener que enviarlos como parámetros.

En el page load debes de detectar cuando se realiza un PostBack y llamar al metodo **BuscarAnuncio**.

```
 if (IsPostBack)
 {
     BuscarAnuncio();
 }
```

Comment: lo que entiendo es que desde el metodo BuscarAnuncio puedo directamente pasar como parametros al strored procedure los textbox de la siguiente forma:::: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@titulo", txtTitulo.text== "" ? (object)DBNull.Value : txtTitulo.text); para ya no pasarlos como parametros del metodo::: BuscarAnuncio(string tituloAnuncio, DateTime fechaInicial, DateTime fechaFinal) y el metodo ya queda libre de pasarle parametros y quedaria simplemente ::::BuscarAnuncio()?